# Python Connect 4 Game

Tags: python

```
COLUMNS = 5
ROWS = 4

def empty_board():
    board_rows =["|   \t\t  |"] * ROWS
    board_columns = [" ___ "] * COLUMNS
    for i in range (ROWS):
        print(board_rows[i])
    print("+", end= " " )   
    for i in range(COLUMNS):
        print(board_columns[i], end="")
        print 
    print("+")
    for i in range(COLUMNS):
        column_number = i+1
        print("   " + str(column_number), end = " ")

def column_choice():
    player = 1
    if player % 2 != 0 :
        column = input("Player 1, please choose a column to make your next move ")
    else:
        column = input("Player 2, please choose a column to make your next move ")
    player += 1
    return column 


def new_board(column):
    moves = 0
    column = int(column) - 1
    if moves % 2 == 0:
        key = "X"
    else:
        key = "O"
    board_rows = ["|   \t\t  |"] * ROWS
    board_columns = [" ___ "] * COLUMNS
    for i in range (ROWS):
        print(board_rows[i])
        board_rows.pop(column)
        board_rows = board_rows.insert(column, key)
        print(board_rows)
    print("+", end= " " )   
    for i in range(COLUMNS):
        print(board_columns[i], end="")
    print("+")
    for i in range(COLUMNS):
        column_number = i+1
        print("   " + str(column_number), end = " ")    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print()
    print("Welcome to Connect 4")
    print()
    new_board(column_choice())
```

I have to create a connect 4 board with the given column and row dimensions (for now). I currently have the board created, but I can't quite figure out how to get the `X` or `O` to go in the correct spot. For instance, right now when I run the program, the `X` will go in the whole column. If you could offer any help I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

```
board_rows =["|   \t\t  |"] * ROWS
board_columns = [" ___ "] * COLUMNS
```

points each entry/item in the list to the same memory address, so changing one column changes them all since they each point to the same place.

```
for row in board_rows:
    print id(row)
```

Use list comprehension or a for loop instead to get different items (memory location) in the list.

```
board_rows =["|   \t\t  |" for row in ROWS]
for row in board_rows:
    print id(row)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that just gave me an endless loop. Probably still not doing something right

Comment: There is nothing in my code or yours that would create an endless loop.  Are you sure that the program is not just waiting for some input.  Also new_board() and empty_board() both contain the same code so you are creating a new, empty board each time either one of those functions is called.  And column_choice() sets the player to 1 each time it is called, so the player never changes.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, that is a very complicated way to represent a textual board. I would recommend, if possible, using an object-oriented approach, such as making the board into a list of lists, where every entry in the list is an list of strings that represents a row, with a `__repr__` method to help visualize it more easily. Here is an example I wrote.

```
class Board(object):

def __init__(self, rows, columns):
    self.rows = rows
    self.columns = columns
    self.board = [['_' for i in range(self.columns)] for i in range(self.rows)]
def __repr__(self):
    board = ''
    for row in self.board:
        board += ''.join(row) + '\n'
    return board

       f = Board(5, 5)
=> None
   f
=> _____
   _____
   _____
   _____
   _____
```

This way, a blank board is represented as a dual list-comprehension, where your rows parameter is the vertical length, and your columns parameter is the horizontal length.

With this code, try writing a method to add a piece onto the board, by finding the lowest point in a column that isn't the opponents piece.

Comment: thank you. That would definitely be very helpful, but I've never learned any of those  functions before so I don't feel comfortable using them